# How to make pd.read_csv read 'null' as np.nan?

Tags: pandas, csv

I have a csv file:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume
1980-12-12,0.513393,0.515625,0.513393,0.513393,0.023106,117258400
1980-12-15,0.488839,0.488839,0.486607,0.486607,0.021900,43971200
1980-12-16,0.453125,0.453125,0.450893,0.450893,0.020293,26432000
1980-12-17,0.462054,0.464286,0.462054,0.462054,0.020795,21610400
1980-12-18,0.475446,0.477679,0.475446,0.475446,0.021398,18362400
1980-12-19,0.504464,0.506696,0.504464,0.504464,0.022704,12157600
1980-12-22,null,null,null,null
```

**pd.read_csv** could read the csv into a dataframe, but it could not transfer the null to **np.nan**, rather it read everything as str.

I can do this work manually in later process, but the column type change is troublesome, as I need to differentiate int and float one by one, is there any way I could use read_csv to deal null as np.nan initially?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pd.read_csv(na_values = 'null', sep = ',')
```